# send sms with jsmpp from remote machine

Tags: java, sms, centos

0 [main] INFO org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession  - Connected
 INFO [org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession] Starting PDUReaderWorker with processor de                                       gree:3 ...
23 [Thread-1] INFO org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession  - Starting PDUReaderWorker wit                                       h processor degree:3 ...
Success  connect and bind to host
 INFO [org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession] Starting EnquireLinkSender
92 [Thread-2] INFO org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession  - Starting EnquireLinkSender
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                       java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                       sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa                                       der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jsmpp.DefaultPDUSender.sendSubmitSm(DefaultPDUSender.java:201)
        at org.jsmpp.SynchronizedPDUSender.sendSubmitSm(SynchronizedPDUSender.ja                                       va:192)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SubmitSmCommandTask.executeTask(SubmitSmCommandTask                                       .java:86)
        at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.                                       java:248)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.submitShortMessage(SMPPSession.java:320                                       )
        at co.il.neo.sms.smpp.SmsSender.sendSMS(SmsSender.java:95)
        at co.il.neo.sms.smpp.SmsSender.main(SmsSender.java:158)

Hi all, this exception is thrown from a remote machine, I can't debug it remotely because I don't have access to it. Searched for jarinjar exception cause but got nothing on Sun's bug track. Have anybody seen this before and can assist, I will be grateful

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a failure when the SMPP enquire link is sent, or about to be sent.

You should look at org.jsmpp.DefaultPDUSender.sendSubmitSm(DefaultPDUSender.java:201)

ie, [line #201 in org/jsmpp/DefaultPDUSender.java](http://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/source/browse/trunk/src/java/main/org/jsmpp/DefaultPDUSender.java#201)

Note, that link may be wrong depending on the version you have deployed.

Looks like an argument into pduComposer.submitSm is null. You'll have to trace the parameters you're submitting into SMPPSession.submitShortMessage and see what is null that makes it's way into submitSm.

Interesting package naming scheme on your packages, by the way.